it was found that the seq for flush memcache was the same in cnosdb

./cnosdb --version
cnosdb 2.4.1,
Will there be any impact when writing a large amount of data and refreshing the memcache during use, which will print this log.
Does this comply with the program operation process,
Will it cause duplicate flush.
